# Access case class parameter inside a map with default

Tags: scala

I have a map whose values are case classes, and I want to access one parameter of that case class with a default value if they map doesn't contain the provided key.

```
myMap.get(myKey).map(_.valueParam).getOrElse(defaultParam)
```

intellij-scala suggests that this is a "simplifiable operation on collection” -- is there a more idiomatic way to write this?

*

Edit/Answer: The alternative approach would be to use

```
myMap.get(myKey).fold(defaultParam)(valueParam)
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  We usually review more code than this.  In particular, I would like to see where `myMap` is defined and loaded.  As stands, this is more of a Stack Overflow question.  Questions asking for help writing code are [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Got it, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map has a getOrElse option:

```
myMap.getOrElse(myKey,defaultParameter).valueParameter
```

Comment: You should rename `defaultParameter` since it is actually the container of the default parameter.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted (would rather not have to create an entire object when I just want to access a parameter) but perhaps that isn't possible to do any differently than in the question. In either case, I'll have to follow up elsewhere.